# gstreamer streaming TS stream (with sound) to RTMP server stops on prerolling

Tags: linux, gstreamer, rtmp

I want be able to stream couple chunks which have TS as a container. If I stream only audio or video, then it's fine. But when I do both simultaneously a pipeline doesn't start. It says prerolling for a long time.

I've tried hints from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983043/remultiplexing-a-stream-with-gstreamer-stops-in-prerolling). It makes my pipeline easier but still prerolling at start.

I believe there is a problem with `tsdemux`. Don't really know why it happens. Logs are not so informative, so I ended up writing this post.

Here is my pipeline. It's not perfect and I know it, but separatly it works. So let's stick with it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="chunck%d.ts" index = 0 ! tsdemux name=demux
demux. !queue ! h264parse ! mux.
demux. ! queue ! faad ! audoconvert ! voaacenc !
flvmux name=mux ! filesink location=stream.ts
```

It this one I've used `filesink` for testing purposes. I know about `rtmpsink` and have tried it before.

Thx a lot.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to combine video and audio. But there is a problem with skipping frames when using my pipeline.

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=0 multifilesrc location="chunk%d.ts" index = 0 ! tsdemux name=demux !
queue ! h264parse ! flvmux name=mux ! queue ! filesink location=stream.flv
demux. ! queue  ! aacparse ! mux.audio
```

Next task is to get rid of the problem. Maybe it's the parser issue. Will see.

Comment: I think you are missing video encoder (at least) - try to add x264enc before h264parse. Also why are you using flvmux if you have filesink output .ts (mistake)? dont you need mpegtsmux instead?

Comment: Originally I have to use `rtmpsink` and it has capability only with video/x-flv. That's why I have it there. I'll try to apply an encoder. Thx.